# SoapClient request is not returning any data

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to figure out how to use a SOAP interface.

I have managed to put together a code after exploring with soapUI.

Working soapUI request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v22="https://shop.textalk.se/webservice/v22">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v22:GetOrders>
         <Login>
            <Shop>23946</Shop>
            <Username>user@mysite.com</Username>
            <Password>HIDDEN</Password>
         </Login>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <Orders>44753668</Orders>
         <Status>All</Status>

      </v22:GetOrders>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Non working PHP request:

```
<?php

        $wsdl = "https://shop.textalk.se/webservice/v22/?WSDL";

        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
            'Shop'=>'23946',
            'Username'=>'user@mysite.com',
            'Password'=>'HIDDEN',
            'trace'=>1,
            'exceptions'=>0));

$request = array(
    'GetOrdersResponse' => array(
        'Orders' => '44753668',
        'Status' => 'All'
    ),
);

         $response = $client->GetOrders($request);
var_dump($response);





    echo $response;


    ?>
```

Documentation is here: https://shop.textalk.se/webservice/v22/wsdldoc.php

When I run the php code absolutely nothing happens

Comment: When I run the php code absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? This is not really a SoapUI problem, so why tag your question with it? If your company needs this ASAP, is there anyone there that could help you? Can you get any other service anywhere to work in php? Can you insert extra logging in your code to help you figure out what is going on?

Comment: I don't thin I have tagged it wrongly since people who know soapUI can easily find and help me port it. Also no there are no one to help me that's exactly why I'm posting here! I am doing this project on spare time but we would save a lot of time in work if I got this working. I don't know much about PHP but I have very high general computer skills and always get my stuff working sooner or later. But I don't know how to work through PHP logs. This must be so simple for people who are used to SOAP and it would help me so much so I am begging for help

Comment: You could start by sending a request instead of the response message you are sending now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. I had to pass the login values as an array, and not as separate values. That solved it. I am now getting correct data in return.

```
<?php
    $wsdl = "https://shop.textalk.se/webservice/v22/?WSDL";

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

    $request = array(
        'Login' => array(
            'Shop'=>"23946",
            'Username'=>"mail@mysite.com",
            'Password'=>"HIDDEN"),
            'Orders' => "44753668",
            'Status' => "All");

    $response = $client->GetOrders($request);
    var_dump($response);
    echo $response;


?>
```

Comment: Good you solved the problem. You got a pointer in the right direction though! In the end it was a matter of reading the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a PHP expert but have you tried the below code?

```
<?php
    $wsdl = "https://shop.textalk.se/webservice/v22/?WSDL";

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

    $request = array(
                'Shop'=>'23946',
                'Username'=>'user@mysite.com',
                'Password'=>'HIDDEN',
                'Orders' => '44753668',
                'Status' => 'All'));

    $response = $client->GetOrders($request);
    var_dump($response);
    echo $response;
?>
```

Check out this blog post for a good starting point http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/

Note: the code is untested!

Comment: That code returns nothing either. I have checked out that tutorial before without much luck. No examples uses logins :/

Comment: Got it working now by making the login parameters an array :)